# Generating FIR filter in Web Audio API

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters

[I'm creating an HTML](https://github.com/dyang304/Noise_Gen.html/blob/master/Noise_Gen.html) that applies a low-pass Windowed Sinc filter with a window size of 8192 to white, pink, or Brownian noise. There are nine radio buttons, eight of which set a cutoff frequency and one which disables the filter.

I've got the noise generator working, with all three "colours" generating noise with no problem.

I've been looking for a way to implement a Windowed Sinc filter using the Blackman window in JavaScript. I've found one site that [seemed to be pretty promising,](http://www.falstad.com/dfilter/DFilter.htm)
but on that site, the event listeners are implemented and the processing itself is done (in a script called "dfilter-0.js") which is *extremely* large and messy. There are so many unnecessary functions and chains of functions that I can never figure out where anything is or what anything does.

My question is, could I get some help cleaning up the "dfilter-0.js" (none of the online tools I've found worked)? Or alternatively, how does one implement a low pass Windowed Sinc filter with the parameters (cutoff frequency, Blackman window size) and connect it to an AudioContext?

I've found [an Audacity plugin](https://forum.audacityteam.org/download/file.php?id=12003) that performs the filtering that I want, but it uses the Nyquist language. How would I implement that in JavaScript and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into FIR filters this week for [another reason](https://mysterypancake.github.io/Houdini-Fun/TimeSmoothing), and had a go implementing one with ConvolverNode as Marcus suggested.

I found a library called [fili.js](https://github.com/markert/fili.js) and used the [FIR code](https://github.com/markert/fili.js/blob/master/src/firCoeffs.js) from there with minor edits for the blackman window. It seems to work OK, though I'm not sure what number to use as the filter's order.

```js
// From https://github.com/markert/fili.js
function createLowpassKernel(sampleRate, cutoff, order) {
    const omega = 2 * Math.PI * cutoff / sampleRate;
    const kernel = new Float32Array(order + 1);
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i <= order; i++) {
        // Sinc impulse
        const offset = i - order / 2;
        const impulse = offset === 0 ? omega : Math.sin(omega * offset) / offset;

        // Blackman window
        const theta = 2 * Math.PI * (i / order);
        const win = 0.42 - 0.5 * Math.cos(theta) + 0.08 * Math.cos(theta * 2);

        // Apply the blackman window to the sinc impulse
        const result = impulse * win;
        kernel[i] = result;
        sum += result;
    }

    // Normalize kernel
    for (let i = 0; i <= order; ++i) {
        kernel[i] /= sum;
    }

    return kernel;
}

let audioCtx;

function setupAudio() {
    // Create a new audio context if necessary
    if (audioCtx) return;
    audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();

    // Make a lowpass kernel based on an order and cutoff
    const order = 8192;
    const cutoff = 2000;
    const sampleRate = audioCtx.sampleRate;
    const kernel = createLowpassKernel(sampleRate, cutoff, order);

    // Create a convolver to apply the kernel
    const convolver = audioCtx.createConvolver();
    convolver.connect(audioCtx.destination);

    // Create a buffer source to play audio for convolving
    const bufferSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    bufferSource.connect(convolver);

    // Convolvers require an ArrayBuffer, so make one from the Float32Array
    const arrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, order + 1, sampleRate);
    arrayBuffer.copyToChannel(kernel, 0);
    convolver.buffer = arrayBuffer;

    // Fetch and play audio through the convolution filter
    fetch("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3")
        .then(data => data.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
        .then(audio => {
            bufferSource.buffer = audio;
            bufferSource.start();
        });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setupAudio();">Setup Audio</button>
```

That being said, it's much easier to use a [BiquadFilterNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode). Though biquad filters are IIR, you can get a pretty similar result with a couple of layers in a butterworth formation.

Answer (score -1):

A FIR filter is just a "block" of coefficients, a vector, being convolved with your signal.

Hence, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ConvolverNode is kind of audio filtering object you need to create and apply.

Comment: So, I have a function that calculates the impulse response for a Blackman window as an array of numbers. Can I just input that as the buffer for a ConvolverNode?